# How can I use selenium options when a class is inherited from (webderiver.Firefox)

Tags: python, selenium, oop, inheritance

Simple using of options in python selenium is easy:

```
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.headless=True

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

driver.get('https://lxml.de')
print(driver.title)
```

This is the code I understand.
My question is how to use options with OOP when a class has an inheritance from (webdriver.Firefox).
Like in this code:

```
class Get_selenium_dynamic_data(webdriver.Firefox):
    

    def __init__(self, teardown=True):

        self.teardown = teardown
        super(Get_selenium_dynamic_data, self).__init__()

        self.implicitly_wait(10)
        self.maximize_window()
```

Obviously things like these don't work:

```
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.headless=True
class Get_selenium_dynamic_data(webdriver.Firefox(options=options)):
```

neither this one:

```
class Get_selenium_dynamic_data(webdriver.Firefox):
    def __init__(self, teardown=True):
        options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
        options.headless=True
        self(option=options)
        #self = self(option=options)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has nothing to do with selenium and applies to OOP's inheritance mechanic only.
When an instance is initiated like this `driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)` `webdriver.Firefox`'s `__init__` takes the passed `options` argument and writes it to the instance's namespace.

But, if there is new `Get_selenium_dynamic_data` class that has `__init__` of its own then `webdriver.Firefox`'s `__init__` is going to be rewritten, and there would be no tool to write the `options` object to the instance namespace in a proper way.

So the solution to the problem is easy and trivial: we need to just take a piece of the `webriver.Firefox`'s `__init__` that works with options and reuse it in `Get_selenium_dynamic_data`. The best way to do in is super() function.

Final working code looks like this:

```
class Get_selenium_dynamic_data(webdriver.Firefox):
    
    def __init__(self, teardown=True, headless=False):

        if headless:
            opt = Options()
            opt.headless = True
            super(Get_selenium_dynamic_data, self).__init__(options=opt)
```

We can initiate an instance like this:

`with Get_selenium_dynamic_data(headless=True) as driver:`
with headless as boolean argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an argument

```
class Get_selenium_dynamic_data(webdriver.Firefox):
    def __init__(self, teardown=True, options=None):
        self.options = options
```

and then create an instance

```
driver = Get_selenium_dynamic_data(options=webdriver.FirefoxOptions())
```

Comment: In what place I can add new options (=change options) ? like: `options.headless=True`

Comment: @DmitriyNeledva `driver.options.headless = True`

Comment: I don't know why but it does not work. Whatever I try wherever I place it a browser shows up anyway.

Comment: @DmitriyNeledva that's because you need to define options before creating instance of webdriver

Comment: In the prev comment you've said that definition of options is to be like `driver.options.headless = True` that means the instance (here `driver`) is already created. How then to define options before getting an instance?  I guess I've tried everything and seems to be like `self.options = options` isn't the equivalent of `webdriver.Firefox(options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()) #set with headless=true`